# JSONParser Error

Tags: php, android, json

Hi i am fairly new in developing an android application. I found this code on the internet that connects an android app to a database and i implemented it in a project. however the app returns an error "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

this is the JSONParser code

```js
package com.example.halfway;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
 
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
 
import android.util.Log;
public class JSONParser {
  static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";
  
     // constructor
     public JSONParser() {
     }
     public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
             List<NameValuePair> params) throws JSONException {
  
         // Making HTTP request
         try {
  
             // check for request method
             if(method == "POST"){
                 // request method is POST
                 // defaultHttpClient
                 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
  
                 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                 HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                 is = httpEntity.getContent();
  
             }else if(method == "GET"){
                 // request method is GET
                 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                 url += "?" + paramString;
                 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
  
                 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                 HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                 is = httpEntity.getContent();
             }           
  
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
  
         try {
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                     is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             is.close();
             json = sb.toString();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
         }
  
         // try parse the string to a JSON object
         try {
             jObj = new JSONObject(json);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
         }
  
         // return JSON String
         return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
  
     }
}
```

and this is the php file that i uploaded in a web server

```js
<?php
  
// include db connect class
require_once './db_connect.php';
 
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
 
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["FIRSTNAME"]) && isset($_GET["LASTNAME"]) && isset($_GET["MIDDLENAME"])) {
    $FIRSTNAME = $_GET['FIRSTNAME'];
 $LASTNAME = $_GET['LASTNAME'];
 $MIDDLENAME = $_GET['MIDDLENAME'];
 
    // get a registry from registrys table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM registry WHERE FIRSTNAME = $FIRSTNAME" AND LASTNAME = 'LASTNAME' AND MIDDLENAME = 'MIDDLENAME');
 
    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 
            $registry = array();
            $registry["FIRSTNAME"] = $result["FIRSTNAME"];
            $registry["MIDDLENAME"] = $result["MIDDLENAME"];
            $registry["LASTNAME"] = $result["LASTNAME"];
            $registry["LICENSENUMBER"] = $result["LICENSENUMBER"];
            $registry["ADDRESS"] = $result["ADDRESS"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;
 
            // user node
            $response["Driver"] = array();
 
            array_push($response["Driver"], $registry);
 
            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no registry found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No registry found";
 
            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no registry found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No registry found";
 
        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
 
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is the error log

```js
02-20 08:18:15.735: E/JSON Parser(20570): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570): org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after var at character 6 of {var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:379)
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at com.example.halfway.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:92)
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at com.example.halfway.License$GetProductDetails$1.run(License.java:129)
02-20 08:18:15.745: W/System.err(20570):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-20 08:18:15.755: W/System.err(20570):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-20 08:18:15.755: W/System.err(20570):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
02-20 08:18:15.755: W/System.err(20570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
02-20 08:18:15.755: W/System.err(20570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-20 08:18:15.755: W/System.err(20570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-20 08:18:15.755: W/System.err(20570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
02-20 08:18:15.755: W/System.err(20570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post the full error log.

Comment: please help me i have a deadline to make please

Comment: Actually, it's not the purpose of stackoverflow to find bugs or assist people on their projects (this is - I guess - also the reason your question was downvoted). But I gave you an answer anyway.

Comment: i know i'm just desperate

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that instead of the JSON response your Android client is getting JavaScript and HTML code, i.e. a webpage is delivered to your client instead of pure JSON.

You should test your PHP code separately first: Open a web browser, run your script with the get parameters and see if you get the correct json response. If you get a correct JSON response, the second step would be to check if your client submits the correct get parameters to the server.

Comment: one last question, is it possible that the error lies in the server that i am using?

Comment: As I said, you have to test the PHP code on your server first. You can do this in a web browser.